# can we have Telerik DatePicker by default in Year Mode

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, datepicker, telerik-mvc

I am using Telerik Date Picker for ASP.Net MVC Razor Form.

In this form for Date of Birth field i am using Telerik Control.

code is as Below

```
@(Html.Telerik().DatePicker()
                                .Name("DOB")
                                .Value(Model.DOB))
```

My requirement is when we click on the calender icon of Date Picker, it will show the day from there we have to navigate to month and year.

to avoid this. I want the calender to show years first and navigate from there.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently supported by the Telerik date picker.

Day view is always the default.

Comment: that is unfortunate. Is there any other control that we can use to get this functionality

Comment: @HaBo I believe Telerik are considering this for a future release. Personally, I wouldn't use a date picker for date of birth. I only use date pickers in instances where the user doesn't know the exact date they wish to select. Could you simply use three Telerk dropdowns or a basic DatePicker? Check out designs to avoid here to understand reasons not to use complex input types for known dates :) http://www.useit.com/alertbox/20001112.html

Answer (score 0):

Someone has posted a solution on their forums, as a workaround: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/datepicker/set-datepicker-default-view-to-year-selection.aspx